# Spring Boot and Resolving Resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bootstrapping

I have a new Spring Boot app and I would like to use a wrap bootstrap template
In my src/main/resources folder I have the following folder structure
templates/fonts
templates/scripts
templates/styles

I am trying to map these resources so they can be picked up in my html code using the following code

```
   @Configuration

public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{


    private static final String templateFolder = "/templates/slim/client";
    private static final String localCSSFolder = "/templates/slim/.tmp";

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        LOG.info("Entered addResourceHandlers");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/fonts/**").addResourceLocations("templates/fonts/**");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/scripts/**").addResourceLocations("templates/scripts/**");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/styles/**").addResourceLocations("templates/styles/**");

        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    } 

}
```

However when I look for a file like scripts/home.js - it is not being returned to me and I get a 404

Can anyone offer any advise so I can get this mapping running correctly?

Thank you
Damien

Comment: Put all your web content in a folder /resources/static; Spring Boot will package them correctly.

Comment: Yes my index.html file is loading fine but unfortunately my resources are not for some reason

Comment: What templating engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/");
```

/Edit:

Put your scripts in src/main/resources/static/what/ever.js

Comment: that did the trick - sorry I also had a type - thanks for your help